# TinyMCE popups too small in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tinymce

This problem only occurrs in Chrome, even after disabling all extensions and restarting Chrome.

In TinyMCE 3.5.8 editor, after clicking on "Insert/Edit Image" icon which opens a dialog box, the dialog is very small. I created a fiddle http://fiddle.tinymce.com/R1daab illustrating this. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is how the dialog should look like (and how it looks in all other browsers):

[image]

What to do to make the dialogs open with correct size in Chrome?

Comment: This might help if you have access to tweak your TinyMCE install : http://techwhet.jduy.com/2013/04/tinymce-pop-up-window-too-small-auto.html

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to fix this for chrome?

Comment: I haven't figured out how to fix it, but when I follow the tinymce fiddle link right now, the "Add Image" dialog appears OK in my Chrome 33.0.1750.117. I checked on my sites which use TinyMce without the inlinepopups plugin and it's also OK. Looks like it's fixed in Chrome? By the way, if you have this issue, try the inlinepopups plugin suggested in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `template_popup_height` and `template_popup_width` properties?